# How to clear systemwide broadcast message?

Tags: linux

OS is Debian 12. I'm running tmux + quite a few sessions containing a large number of windows, instances of vim, etc. I unfortunately got a system broadcast message that seems to have polluted every single window. How do I clear this globally with a single command? I really want to avoid having to clear this manually in every single window.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't undo the effect of the message globally.

You might be able to paste <kbd>Ctrl L</kbd> into each window's application but there's no guarantee that would do anything useful - and it's quite possible it could do damage in certain (unknown) circumstances